# x axis domain/range in a plot

Tags: pgfplots, plot

Please consider the following code of a plot and its result. What I want to be shown in the plot is the actual values of the x axis i.e 1000, 5000, 10000 and not 0.1*10^4, 0.5*10^4 , 1*10^4 to be written horizontally or vertically. How can this be done?
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=0:20000]
\addplot  [color=cyan,mark=*] coordinates{
(0,40.73) (257,41.13) (528,41.89) (774,41.90) (1036,42.72) (1291,42.92) (1564,43.39 (1810,43.97) (2082,44.48) (2347,45.07) (2628,45.99) (2889,46.41) (3178,47.07) (3459,47.59) (3729,47.81) (4004,48.05) (4275,48.21) (4526,48.33) (4792,48.56) (5052,48.99) (5305,48.98) (5572,49.47) (5815,49.42) (6073,49.65) (6328,49.75) (6591,50.12) (6862,50.22) (7159,50.61) (7428,50.76) (7689,50.94) (7945,50.99) (8234,50.84) (8484,51.04) (8747,51.13) (9000,51.25) (9254,51.31) (9519,51.48) (9792,51.45) (10079,51.83) (10342,52.00) (10612,52.13) (10863,52.41) (11137,52.55) (11402,52.92) (11685,53.18) (11963,53.27) (12218,53.22) (12500,53.52) (12787,53.54) (13058,53.84) (13322,53.76) (13573,53.86) (13836,53.76) (14088,53.83) (14348,53.90) (14630,54.03) (14872,54.05) (15128,54.36) (15387,54.15) (15630,54.14) (15895,54.57) (16130,54.61) (16391,54.56) (16636,54.65) (16890,54.71) (17139,54.91) (17385,55.02) (17635,55.16) (17897,55.42) (18157,55.56) (18442,55.48) (18673,55.78) (18933,55.91)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `scaled ticks = false` to the axis options.